# vuejs object el showing as <!----> in markup

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When mounting an element to my vue object, the element becomes  in the resulting marking for some reason.  As a result, nothing works.

The element I am mounting to is a dynamic element appended by javascript rather than being hard coded into the html, but I made sure to append the element before mounting.  This problem does not exist when mounting to an element hard coded into the html.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
let X = new Vue({
    template: '<some-template></some-template>',
    components: { 'some-component' : someImportedComponent }
});
let component = X.$mount();
element.append(component.$el);
```

Comment: How are you mounting the element?

Comment: let x = new Vue{ template: '<some-element></some-element>'

Comment: let x = new Vue{ 
  template: '<some-element></some-element>',
  components: { 'component' : someImportedComponent }
}
someImportedComponent.$el.$mount();

/* im terribly sorry i can't recall, i will check tmr morning when i have access to the code again */